# Connect to linked server (Oracle) in SQL Server using Instant Client

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, linked-server, instantclient

I need to connect to a remote database (Oracle) using a MS SQL Server (2019) linked server. What I did so far:

1. Installed Oracle Instant Client x64 and the ODBC drivers on the machine where the SQL server is running
2. Created a symlink to the central TNSNAMES.ORA (on a file share in the network) inside the Oracle Instant client folder.
3. Set the necessary environment variables
4. Created an ODBC connection to the database on the Oracle server on this machine
5. Restarted MS SQL Server
6. Created a linked server (Microsoft OLEDB Provider for ODBC Drivers) in the SQL instance

When connecting to the SQL Server using sqlcmd on this machine (I did not install SSMS there), I can query the linked database using OPENQUERY(). I can also read the file TNSNAMES.ORA using this command (note, the given file is the symlink, but it displays the contents of the linked file, as it should):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\InstantClientx64\tnsnames.ora', SINGLE_CLOB) TNSNames
```

So far, everything is fine.

Now, when I connect to the SQL Server from my workstation using SSMS, i get the following error when trying to read TNSNAMES.ORA using the command above:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\InstantClientx64\tnsnames.ora" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
```

I created a file test.txt in the instant client folder containing something like "Am I allowed to read this?" - and I was, no problems.

I started procmon on the server to find out what happens. When using the above command on the SQL server,  I get a REPARSE (because it's a link!), and then SUCCESS, the file is displayed in the sqlcmd console.

When using this command in SSMS (on my local workstation), first appears the REPARSE (OK), then ACCESS DENIED.

In both cases it is the same user account which is displayed as "Impersonating" in the procmon's details. There is definitely no problem with a firewall, and the read permissions on the tnsnames.ora file on the network share are granted for Everyone. I am also able to create an ODBC item on the local workstation, and can connect and query the database from here.

I have done this in the past I don't know how often, and never had problems. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to read the tnsnames.ora file via SQL?  The Oracle libraries will (should) internally open it and use it when your app connects to the DB.

The default location for network config files is shown in the Instant Client installation doc.  In your case it will be `C:\InstantClientx64\network\admin`.  Unless you have set the `TNS_ADMIN` variable, then start by creating this subdirectory and putting tnsnames.ora in it.

(A future version of Instant Client on Windows will create the `network\admin` subdirectory automatically, similar to the way it is created with the Linux Instant Client packages).

Comment: I am not trying to read the tnsnames.ora file via SQL, I am trying to add a linked server in SQL Server using an ODBC connection that uses the Instant Client. The ODBC connection works, but when I try to create the linked server, I get this error.

I have set the TNS_ADMIN variable properly (otherwise, the ODBC connection would not work)